# How to get the Table Ids and the Value on clicking a row element in a particular column from multiple tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I need some help to write a javascript function to retrieve the clicked value as well as the table id upon clicking a particular column(Tier) from multiple tables.

For example, when I click on Tier 1, I am trying to assign it to tier_token and set the client based on the table id --> tier_token=Tier 1, client=products.
If I click on Tier 2 , tier_token=Tier 1, client=products .
If I click on Tier 1 from the customers' table, tier_token=Tier 1 and client=customers, and so on.

In my script, I have been using `document.getElementById`, I would like to have something which I could use for multiple table ids at the same time, retrieve that id value, and set it to the variable client - because although I have listed just a couple of tables, I need to define multiple tables later.

Also, I would like to allow the clicks only on the Tier column and prevent the clicks on the Points column.

```
<html>
<table class="table" id="products">
<tr>
    <th>Tier</th>
    <th>Points</th>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Tier1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Tier2</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Tier3</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
 
  <table class="table" id="customers">
   <tr>
    <th>Tier</th>
    <th>Points</th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Tier1</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Tier2</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Tier3</td>
    <td>500</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Tier4</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Script:

```
<script>
var table = document.getElementById("customers");
    if (table != null) {
        for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
            table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
                tableText(this);
            };
        }
    }
    function tableText(tableCell) {
        //alert(tableCell.innerHTML);
        var tier_token=tableCell.innerHTML;
        var client = "customers";
        console.log("Tier:"+ tier_token);
        console.log("Client:"+ client);
        alert("Tier:"+ tier_token + "Client:"+ client);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$("table td:first-child")` selector this will get called only when first td is clicked then inside this handler use `.text()` to get text of td which is clicked and `closest('table').attr('id')` to get id of table.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//click only on first child(1st columns tds)
$("table td:first-child").on("click", function() {
  var texts = $(this).text(); //get text of td which is clicked
  var ids_ = $(this).closest("table").attr('id') //get clsest table where click event has taken place using that get `id` of table
  console.log("TEXT " + texts + " ID " + ids_)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="products">
  <tr>
    <th>Tier</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tier1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tier2</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tier3</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table" id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Tier</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tier1</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tier2</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tier3</td>
    <td>500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tier4</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***Read more*** :

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

https://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

```js
//click only on first child(1st columns tds)
$("table td:first-child").on("click", function() {
  var texts = $(this).text(); //get text of td which is clicked
  var ids_ = $(this).closest("table").attr('id') //get clsest table where click event has taken place using that get `id` of table
  console.log("TEXT " + texts + " ID " + ids_)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="products">
  <tr>
    <th>Tier</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tier1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tier2</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tier3</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table" id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Tier</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tier1</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tier2</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tier3</td>
    <td>500</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tier4</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.